# Keep selection/cursor when clicking outside of Jodit editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, jodit

Is there any way to keep the current selection inside a `Jodit-editor`, when clicking outside of it? E.g. I'd like to have a button completely outside the editor (e.g. in a sidebar of the application) that can insert some elements in the editor window at the current position.

You can store the selection by using `editor.selection.save()` and it will be temporarily written in the markup. This can be restored using `editor.selection.restore()`. This mechanism would actually work for my use-case, but unfortunately, the 'helper-markup' is also removed/reset in the moment of the editor losing focus.

Also, I didn't find something like a 'selection'-event, that I could use to 'remember' the selection in my own state. Plus the selection. The set method from the selection doesn't seem to work, but I haven't dug into that yet.

Comment: I had the same problem too and worked around by using native Selection API to save and restore selection. Another solution that works as well is to avoid removing/reseting selection marker. Can you share how you resolved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems and I have solved that a small trick.
As you know you can catch selection in the "onBlur" event and in there I added a special string for the check after losing focus.
for example "{}".
and then string replace with my want.